# read the currency format

Tags: php, format, currency

perhaps for some people this is easy, but I want to learn

There are 2 currency formats:

first currency format is **1,123,123.12** and this format may be like **$1,123,123.12** or  **1,123,123.12€** and

second currency format is **1.123.123,12** and this may be such **$1.123.123,12** or **1.123.123,12€** so the difference is the placement of dots and commas

The above format will be

```
$this->value('one of the currency format insert here');
```

e.g. `$this->value('$1,123,123.12');` or `$this->value('1.123.123,12€');`

that I want to know is the code 
`if (first currency format) {use blah .. blah ..} elseif (second currency format) {use blah .. blah ..} else {/ / unsupported format}`

so how the code to identify whether the entry is input the first currency format or second currency format?

thanks for the your pointers and ideas.

### **UPDATED:**

I apologize for mistake in giving examples

When I tried to test the code I have a little confused because it seems not working

then I changed my prevoious parts, so that **$value['amount']** it may be use

first currency format *1,123,123.12* and this format may be like **$1,123,123.12** or **1,123,123.12€** and

second currency format *1.123.123,12* and this may be such **$1.123.123,12** or **1.123.123,12€**

then the **value['amount']** will identify first with code like the following conditional

```
class curr_format {

private bla...bla..1
private bla...bla..2
var etc..

    public function curr_format ($bla...,$and_bla..) {

//then make conditional is here
if (first currency format) {//use blah .. blah ..} 
elseif (second currency format) {//use blah .. blah ..} 
else {/ / unsupported format}
//another codes..
```

at the end output as look like:

```
$identify = new curr_format();
echo $identify->curr_format($value['amount'],$else_statement);
```

Comment: Interesting question. Where is the data coming from? Can you rely on the data *always* to be in that format? Because `1,123` and `1.123` can be ambiguous: They could mean 1123 Dollars, or 1.12 Dollars respectively. The best thing to do would be define the input format at time of input

Comment: the data coming from another output code (echoed), so i want to identify what currency format inserted by read the output, thanks Pekka

Answer (score 2):

Check what the 3 last character is, if it is a "," or a ".". Use this to determine your currency format.

```
$value =  "1,123,123.12";
if($value[strlen($value)-3]==',') $currency_format = "A";
else $currency_format="B";
```

Comment: This depends on the amount always to have two decimals, though. It will break if there are more (or less)

Comment: Sorry, does the code also read decimal separator? does it currency format identify with pattern?, Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
function getNumber( $inStr ){
  if( preg_match( '/[\,\.]\d{2}\D?$/' , $inStr ) ){
   # Has 2 Decimal Places
    return (float) preg_replace( '/\D/' , '' , $inStr )/100;
  }
  return (int) preg_replace( '/\D/' , '' , $inStr );
}
```

In cases where there are 2 decimals, we strip all non-digit characters, and then divide by 100 (thereby replacing the decimals).
If there are not 2 decimals, we just strip all non-digit characters.

Comment: hm.. seems interesting, but how i use my conditional code above according to this code/ many thanks

Comment: Hi, I am very sorry, I make a little mistake with my previous code, please have a look to my last code, let me know what i could do?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're only working with dollars and euros (or pounds or anything else that has two decimal digits, the easiest solution is:

```
var value = str_replace('€','',$this->value);

if (substr($value,str_len($value)-3,1)=='.') {
  // first format
}
else if (substr($value,str_len($value)-3,1)==',') {
  // second format
}
else {
  // unsupported
}
```

Otherwise, you would have to set up a loop which iterates back through the characters one by one, or determines the number of digits back based on the currency.

Comment: Good solution, but does not allow for instances with/without a trailing currency character, if I am reading it correctly.

Comment: @Lucanos, yes it does. That's what `var value = str_replace('€','',$this->value);` does.

Comment: Hi, I will test it first, that seem purpose to my conditional code, Thanks for your attentions

Comment: My Apologizes, with my previous mistake, but please let me know how to fix my problems, now I updated my question, please have a look. Thank You